# 3D overlays in MapKit

Tags: ios, 3d, mapkit, overlay

I would like to add overlays with elevation data on MKMapView so that changing the camera allows perspective of these overlays.  Nothing fancy...

Is this possible?  I'm not finding any information on it.

Comment: Nothing fancy huh :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't yet possible. Apple has only opened 2D raster tile overlays thus far, with iOS 7+. The only 3D elements they currently support are (their own) building height data.